# CodeIgniter Access Controller from PHP Require

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my project and I am stuck trying to figure this out.

I have some javascript that needs to perform an AJAX call to fetch some results based on a dropdown value that was selected.

```
function fetchLines(){
 $.ajax({
    url: baseURL + "resources/ajax.php?node=fetchLines",
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    data: {
       lineType: 'business'
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    },
    success: function(data) {

        console.log(data);

    }

});
}
```

In this AJAX file, I am trying to include my controller and then access the function within it.

```
<?php
define('BASEPATH', "AJAX");
require_once('../application/controllers/Project.php');


switch($_REQUEST['node']){

    case 'fetchLines':
        $objLines = new Project();
        $objLines->fetchLines($_REQUEST['lineType']);
    break;

}

?>
```

My CI Controller then has a private function in it which I am trying to call to get the data I need:

```
private function fetchLines($lineType){
    $lines = $this->project_model->fetchLines($lineType);
    return $lines;
}
```

My goal here is to have an AJAX file or controller (if needed) be used for all my AJAX calls. It needs to be able to access a controller and return data.

With the current code above, I am getting the error: `Class 'CI_Controller' not found in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\blueprint\application\controllers
\Project.php`

Is there a better way to handle situations like this? I'm not an expert with OOP but some reading suggested something along these lines.

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks for the info. Is there a better way to approach this? I know I'm not the only one run into a situation like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you are not sending this request to the controller method instead ?

```
        function fetchLines(){
         $.ajax({
            url: baseURL + "controller-name/method-name",
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: {lineType: 'business'},
            error: function(err) {
                alert(err.statusText);
            },
            success: function(data) {

                console.log(data);

            }

        });
        }
```

**NOTE** and in controller you can access these values as

```
function method-name(){
    echo $this->input->get('lineType');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say my ajax file is in the controllers folder
And I want to re-use my controllers, i would do it like this :

```
$this->load->library('../controllers/your_controller'); 
$this->your_controller->_some_method($data);
```

Load the controller as library and used it like a library.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code that listens to AJAX call in a controller function only. The way you are trying to do is not a good practice at all.
If you want a method to be executed only if the request was an XHR i.e.AJAX request then use

`if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
      //your code
}else{
  redirect(base_url())
}`